# Как создать кошелек для токена BSC + SWAP

Tags: token, blockchain, ethereum, криптография, json-rpc

Так имеем **свой токен** с контрактом в сети BSC BEP20
Хотим создать телеграм бота где пользователь получит кошелек BSC bep20 и сможет закидывать туда BNB bep20 и делать swap на **НАШ ТОКЕН** bep20..

Хотел бы узнать на сколько это реально и через какие API можно это все дело сделать.

Что я пробовал делать:

1. Поднял GETH у себя на сервере для получения доступа к Нодам и генерации Адресов с Приватным клю чом KeyStore.
2. Так как наш токен можно свапить в PancakeSwapV2 я взял для свапа API 0x.org но тут я могу поучать quote но не могу сделать свап да и вообще не понимаю как ее делать.

Вопросы:

Что такое **EIP712** и **EthSign**?

Как сделать свап токенов через api используя **KeyStore**?

Как сделать перевод токена через **GETH JSON-RPC** ?

Comment: Делается сайт. Для этого есть кошелек metamask. Его [API](https://docs.metamask.io/guide/#blockchain-connection) можно использовать на сайте  чтобы: отправлять/стейкать/свапать/авторизовываться через него.

Comment: Что вам не нравится в EIP712?

Comment: @DiD, сори, но я уже сильно отчаялся, ничего рабочего не могу найти в гугле, https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1366470/423786 Уже второй вопрос, буду рад если Вы посмотрите

Comment: Ну как ничего рабочего? Все рабочее... ETH, BSC, metamask, Polkadot, Solana, Solidity, Scilla, uniswap, pancakeswap да хоть electrum. Что вам надо то?

Comment: Уже есть даже инструкции о создании своих собственных токенов стандарта BEP-20 в сети Binance Smart Chain (BSC) при помощи Remix IDE

https://domhtml.ru/sozdanie-sobstvennyh-tokenov-standarta-bep-20-v-seti-binance-smart-chain-bsc-pri-pomoshhi-remix-ide/